# Is it possible to program an Android app to automatically divert the user to download a plugin app upon opening it?

Tags: android, plugins, dialog

Say this Android app doesn't work without the plugin, what are the options available to get the plugin downloaded?

Would I have to create a dialog for the user to accept and divert them to the plugin app page on the Play Store to download it?

Can the user be automatically diverted to the plugin app page upon opening the downloaded app?

Comment: yes , you can do everything you asked about

Comment: Ok, if I want the second option (Automatically divert to app page upon opening the downloaded app), how would I do this? I don't need written code. I just want to know the process so I can do further research. Thanks.

Comment: you can check on very first activity of your app redirect to page